# NativeScript delpoy to private device

Tags: ios, nativescript

I m quite new to NativeScript and iOS development therefore I really don't know.

Is it possible to deploy a NativeScript created App to my private iPhone without having a apple developer account or stuff?
If not, is there a testing account or some kind of free-to-play account for testing my apps on my device?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Comment: allright, thought anyone could help in here. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

To install an app to an device you need at least 1 developer account. You can then install apps up to 100 devices from there.

You can also just add your apple-id to an existing account and be a part of that account.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that.